# The realization functor is left adjoint to the singular functor

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

> Proposition 2.2. *The realization functor is left adjoint to the singular functor in the sense that there is an isomorphism*
>
> $$\text{hom}_\mathsf{Top}(|X|, Y) \cong \text{hom}_\mathsf{S}(X, SY)$$
>
> *which is natural in simplicial sets $X$ and topological spaces $Y$.*
>
> Proof: There are isomorphisms
> $$\begin{align}
> \text{hom}_\mathsf{Top}(|X|,Y) 
> &\cong
> \varprojlim_{\Delta^n \to X} \text{hom}_\mathsf{Top}(|\Delta^n|, Y) \\
> &\cong
> \varprojlim_{\Delta^n \to X} \text{hom}_\mathsf{S}(\Delta^n, S(Y) \\
> &\cong 
> \text{hom}_\mathsf{S}(X, SY).
> \end{align}
> $$

This is Proposition 2.2, page 7, (Simplicial
Homotopy Theory, Paul G. Goerss
& John F. Jardine).
I understand the reasons for the first and the third isomorphisms, but I could not figure out the reason for the second isomorphism. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

That's the definition of $S(Y)$: its $n$-simplices are the maps $|\Delta^n|\to Y$. Note there's a Yoneda lemma in here too: $n$-simplices of a simplicial set are morphisms from $\Delta^n$.

Comment: ... and the trick of presheaves that $F \cong \operatorname{Nat}(\mathbf{y}(-), F)$.