# Simplicial set associated to a topological space

Tags: general-topology, simplicial-stuff

Let $X$ be a topological space. We want to associate a simplicial set i.e., a functor $\Delta\rightarrow \underline{\text{Set}}$.

Here $\Delta$ is the category whose

- object set is$ \{[0],[1],[2],\cdots\}$ where $[n]=\{0,1,2\cdots,n\}$, $[0]=\{0\}$.
- by an arrow  $[m]\rightarrow [n]$ we mean a map $f:\{0,1\cdots,m\}\rightarrow \{0,1,2,\cdots,n\}$ such that $f$ is non-decreasing i.e., $f(i)\leq f(j)$ if $i\leq  j$.

Fix $n$.

Let $e_0=(1,0,\cdots,0)\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1},e_1=(0,1,0\cdots,0)\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}, .... , e_n=(0,\cdots,0,1)\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Let $\Delta_n$ be the convex combination of $\{e_0,\cdots,e_n\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. This has induced topology   from $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

By convention, $\Delta_0$ is just a singleton, say $\{0\}$.

For this topological space $X$, we need to define a functor $\Delta\rightarrow \underline{\text{Set}}$.

- For $[0]$, consider the set $\text{Hom}_{\text{Top}}(\Delta_0,X)$ which is collection of all continuous maps from $\{0\}$ to $X$ which is precisely the points of $X$.
- For $[1]$, consider the set  $\text{Hom}_{\text{Top}}(\Delta_1,X)$ which is collection of all paths in $X$.

Similarly, for $[n]$, consider $\text{Hom}_{\text{Top}}(\Delta_n,X)$. For   convenience, set $\Delta_n(X)=\text{Hom}_{\text{Top}}(\Delta_n,X)$.

Given an arrow $f:[m]\rightarrow [n]$ we have a continuous map $f_{\Delta}:\Delta_m\rightarrow \Delta_n$.

This gives maps $\Delta_n(X)\rightarrow \Delta_m(X)$

- $\theta:\Delta_n\rightarrow X$ an element of $\Delta_n(X)$ is assigned to the composition $\theta\circ f_{\Delta}:\Delta_m\rightarrow \Delta_n\rightarrow X$ an element of $\Delta_m(X)$.

This gives a **contravariant** functor $\Delta\rightarrow \underline{\text{Set}}$. This is the simplicial set I am associating to a topological space.

This I heard from some conversation and filled some gaps.

Question is

> Did I understand till here correctly?

Comment: What you have described is a well-known standard construction.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I heard it from someone they explained it vaguely... so, tried to write down..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thoughts are correct, and it is good that you tried to fill the gaps by yourself. If you are further interested in this subject, the functor
$$S : \mathbf{Top} \to \mathbf{sSet}$$
is known as the *singular functor*. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_set, [The realization functor is left adjoint to the singular functor](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2108256) or have a look into a good textbook.

Comment: Yes, I want to understand systematically.... Given a topological space, I have got a simplicial set and given a simplicial set, I want to see what is its geometric realization... Do you have any personal favourite book for this matter?

Comment: I don't have a real favourite. Here are some suggestions.  Simplicial Homotopy Theory by P. Goerss and J. Jardine, https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.4221.pdf, https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/riehl.pdf.

Comment: Thank you :) I will see...